# how can I use EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation outside of a spring container

Tags: java, spring, osgi, aspectj

how can i use EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation outside of a spring container(inside OSGI environment) like the use of JpaRepositoryFactory in Spring Data JPA.

Comment: http://blog.osgi.org/2014/09/how-should-i-use-guicespringblueprint.html

Comment: thanks @BalazsZsoldos.I already use spring data jpa inside my OSGI,but i don't know how to enable EnableAspectJAutoProxy like behavior inside the OSGI environment.

Comment: to be more clear,I have a class with aspect annotation and i want the OSGI environment ensures that MyAspect class will be properly processed and the other class will be proxied mixing in the advice that it contributes.